issue in fetching live data from finnhub
can anyone help me to fetch live data from finnhub I have basic premium version for future instrument E mini S&P 500 and this is symbol "ES=F"
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import time

# Define your Finnhub API token (replace with your actual token)
api_token = 'api key'

# Define the endpoint URL for Finnhub's quote API
base_url = 'https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote'

# Symbol for E-mini S&P 500 futures contract (December 2024)
symbol = 'ES=F'

# Construct the full URL with API token and symbol
url = f'{base_url}?symbol={symbol}&token={api_token}'

# Fetch live OHLC data with timestamp
def fetch_live_data():
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",data)
            # Get the current timestamp when data is fetched
            current_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            # Display the current OHLC data with the timestamp
            print(f"Timestamp: {current_timestamp}")
            print(f"Current OHLC data for {symbol}:")
            print(f"Open: {data['o']}")
            print(f"High: {data['h']}")
            print(f"Low: {data['l']}")
            print(f"Close: {data['c']}")
            print(f"Previous Close: {data['pc']}")
            print("-" * 50)
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch data. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Run the script to fetch data at a defined interval
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        fetch_live_data()
        time.sleep(60)  # Fetch data every 60 seconds (you can adjust this interval)

